# Split a large xml file into multiple based on tag in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a very large xml file which I need to split into several based on a particular tag.
The XML file is something like this:

```xml
<xml>
<file id="13">
  <head>
    <talkid>2458</talkid>
    <transcription>
      <seekvideo id="645">So in college,</seekvideo>
      ...
    </transcription>
  </head>
  <content> *** This is the content I am trying to save *** </content>
</file>
<file>
      ... 
</file>
</xml>
```

I want to extract the **content** of each **file** and save based on the **talkid**.

Here is the code I have tried with:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

all_talks = 'path\\to\\big\\file'

context = ET.iterparse(all_talks, events=('end', ))
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'file':
        content = elem.find('content').text
        title = elem.find('talkid').text
        filename = format(title + ".txt")
        with open(filename, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(ET.tostring(content), encoding='utf-8')
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using `.iterparse()` it's more generic to rely just on events:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

all_talks = Path(r'file.xml')
context = ET.iterparse(all_talks, events=('start', 'end'))

for event, element in context:
    if event == 'end':
        if element.tag == 'talkid':
            title = element.text
        elif element.tag == 'content':
            content = element.text
        elif element.tag == 'file' and title and content:
            with open(all_talks.with_name(title + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
                f.write(content)
    elif element.tag == 'file':
        content = title = None
```

**Upd.** In [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74182062/10824407) @[Leila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11926527/leila) asked how to write text from all `<seekvideo>` tags to file instead of `<content>` to file, so here is a solution:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

all_talks = Path(r'file.xml')
context = ET.iterparse(all_talks, events=('start', 'end'))

for event, element in context:
    if event == 'end':
        if element.tag == 'file' and title and parts:
            with open(all_talks.with_name(title + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
                f.write('\n'.join(parts))
        elif element.text:
            if element.tag == 'talkid':
                title = element.text
            elif element.tag == 'seekvideo':
                parts.append(element.text)
    elif element.tag == 'file':
        title = None
        parts = []
```

Comment: What if I want to extract transcription lines, however, without <seekvideo> tags? Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @Leila, add one more condition `elif element.tag == 'transcription':`

Comment: That doesn't work. The output is blank. I also tried another way with findall(), but again didn't work. Added it as a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182062/extract-recurring-subelements-from-xml-file-in-python

Comment: @Leila, try [this](https://tio.run/##fZE9bwMhDIZ3foU3QI1YulSVbsxadciWVhFtfA0NBwisJP31V3Pks2rrCezXj19M@qJNDPcPKY@jG1LMBIfBG6SMaOYeBwy04DPYAvOF6HMcIFnaePcGR/0zX4Ww3q/I@m2BbsqoLHvn0TBNavEeA@GBuDZfGEeYk80F1blpBrjjSaVTspDNJGcgMayl1kL0Mbcqi5ohcAGOxEcBHK5vCui61tfSp1LrMmQ/JkGd6K41NciRR/Z3FjP8LED/C6YgbndujfEHiZ9GxdiU2Ii6xun/eXVdEmxYH73U08S6xe8dbSAy/LI9U3OrYAdUrfUOpKEDSc1r3EtdP6@/pdTozT7zXyj5EqT5jC6oaZxuPv/2eCGdlvYUA4qb93Ny@TqO3w).

Comment: The last code worked perfectly for English, but when I tried it with another language (Russian), it gave me the following error: `f.write('\n'.join(lines))
TypeError: sequence item 264: expected str instance, NoneType found`. I have already added encoding to `open()`.

Comment: @Leila, one of `<seekvideo>` tags has no text that's why this exception appears. You should learn how to debug your code. Use `elif element.tag == 'seekvideo' and element.text` condition to avoid appending `None` to `parts`.

Comment: @Leila, I've edited code to avoid tags with no text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse xml.

It would like this(i added a second talk id to the xml to demonstrate finding multiple tags)

```py
xml_file = '''<xml>
<file id="13">
  <head>
    <talkid>2458</talkid>
    <transcription>
      <seekvideo id="645">So in college,</seekvideo>
      ...
    </transcription>
     <talkid>second talk id</talkid>
  </head>
  <content> *** This is the content I am trying to save *** </content>
</file>
<file>
      ... 
</file>
</xml>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, "xml")

first_talk_id = soup.find('talkid').get_text()
talk_ids = soup.findAll('talkid')

print(first_talk_id)
# prints 2458


for talk in talk_ids:
    print(talk.get_text())

# prints 
# 2458
# second talk id
```

NOTE: you will need to install a parser for bs4 to work with xml
`pip install lxml` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way..

the issue is that the talkid is a child of the head tag and not the file tag.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

all_talks = 'file.xml'

context = ET.iterparse(all_talks, events=('end', ))
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'file':
        head = elem.find('head')
        content = elem.find('content').text
        title = head.find('talkid').text
        filename = format(title + ".txt")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:  # 'wt' or just 'w' if you want to write text instead of bytes
            f.write(content.encode())    # in which case you would remove the .encode()
```

Comment: This eliminated the error, but it doesn't work. There's no output.

Comment: @Leila When I ran this code on the example xml in your question it created a file called `2458.txt` and it had the `*** This is the content I am trying to save ***`  contents

Comment: That's strange! I even tried it with a smaller .xml file to check if it was affected by the large size, but again no output! Thanks anyway. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @Leila  make sure you are looking in the right directory.

Comment: Sure, but still the same.

Comment: @Leila  also make sure you change the all_talks variable to the correct path... I changed it to test it out myself.   If it still doesn't work then I agree that is strange

Comment: Yeah, I definitely did. Not sure what was the issue.