# Extract recurring subelements from XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a large XML file which I am splitting into separate files.
Here's how the file looks like:

```xml
<xml>
<file id="13">
  <head>
    <talkid>2458</talkid>
    <transcription>
      <seekvideo id="645">THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED</seekvideo>
      <seekvideo id="3349">THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED</seekvideo>
      <seekvideo id="4937">THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED</seekvideo>
      <seekvideo id="7423">THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED</seekvideo>
    </transcription>
  </head>
</file>
</xml>
```

I would like to get all the contents of `seekvideo` tags, regardless of their ids, on separate lines. So the output would be:

```
THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
THIS PART SHOULD BE EXTRACTED
```

Here's what I've tried. The output is printed correctly in the terminal, but when I want to write it in a new file, it doesn't work, and returns a single word only.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

all_talks = Path(r'test.xml')
context = ET.iterparse(all_talks, events=('start', 'end'))

for event, element in context:
    if event == 'end':
        if element.tag == 'talkid':
            title = element.text
        elif  element.tag == 'seekvideo':
            seekvideo = element.text
            # print (seekvideo)
        elif element.tag == 'file' and title and seekvideo:
            with open(all_talks.with_name(title + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
                f.write(seekvideo)
    elif element.tag == 'file':
        seekvideo = title = None
```

Comment: (a) There is no element named `talkid` in your example, so `title` never gets set. (b) you're calling `element.findall('seekvideo')` **on** a `<seekvideo>` element, so that's not going to return any results ever...but (c) you shouldn't be calling `findall` in any case; you're using an iterative parser so you're going to process all the elements anyway.

Comment: Added `talkid`. There are many elements in the file, so I just removed them to make it short here. I have also tried other ways but with no success. Updated the question.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. I also added your answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Olvin-Roght generously answered my question in another post. I'm going to post it here, as it may prove helpful to someone else. Here's how it worked:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

talks = Path(r'path\to\talks.xml')
context = ET.iterparse(all_talks, events=('start', 'end'))

for event, element in context:
    if event == 'end':
        if element.tag == 'talkid':
            title = element.text
        elif  element.tag == 'seekvideo':
            lines.append(element.text)
        elif element.tag == 'file' and title and lines:
            with open(talks.with_name(title + '.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write('\n'.join(lines))
    elif element.tag == 'file':
        title = None
        lines = []
```